# Call ajax when MVC project starts

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

When I start my MVC application I want to call:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "@Url.Action("CreateInstance", "Home")",
   type: "POST"
});
```

This works! But I want to call it only once. If I switch from page to page this function is still getting called. I only want to call the function if I start the project.
Is this possible?

Comment: On the first request of the application / application start? Or the first request of a user?

Comment: First request of the application. If I press start in Visual Studio

Comment: You should probably describe the actual problem you're trying to solve here, because there is probably a better solution then making a ajax call from the client when the application starts.

Comment: I have a constructor that will fill a list. But it only goes to the constructor if i call a method with the Instance of a class that is inherited from the class with the constructor. And i want to fill the list right after I start the project.


`public class ConcreteAlertSubject : AlertSubjectBase
    {
        private static ConcreteAlertSubject _instance;

        public static ConcreteAlertSubject Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return _instance ?? (_instance = new ConcreteAlertSubject());
            }
        }
}`

Comment: The Instance has to be alive before I can do other stuff. I hope you understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to call the code directly in your global.asax . If you aren't outputting any data to the page, why use ajax?

Comment: Using this method will also prevent odd race conditions since the `Application_Start` event is only fired once.

Comment: Ok thanks. But if I close the project and start it right after it then it doesn't do the method `Application_Start()`. Do you know why?